# Create Clickable Icon on Android Toolbar

Tags: android, kotlin, icons, toolbar

So here I am trying to create a clickable icon (add image icon ) on the toolbar. I've seen tutorials on how to do this, and I followed their steps, but for some reason, it does not work for me even though the API is 34. Also, neither the toast nor the log work; I've tested it on both a physical device and the Android emulator built in to Android Studio.

MainActivity.kt:

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.provider.MediaStore.*
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var toolbar : Toolbar
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.topToolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        //Top app bar created
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.top_app_bar, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if(item.itemId == R.id.addImageIcon){
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Add Image icon clicked")
            openGallery()
            return true
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    fun openGallery(){
        Log.d("MainActivity", "openGallery function called")
        Toast.makeText(this, "Menu Item is Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        val intent = Intent(ACTION_PICK_IMAGES)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="409dp"
            android:layout_height="729dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
    
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/topToolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
                    app:menu="@menu/top_app_bar" />
    
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

top_app_bar.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    
        <item
            android:id = "@+id/addImageIcon"
            android:icon="@drawable/baseline_add_photo_alternate_24"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
            android:title=""
            android:contentDescription="@string/add_image"
            />
    
    
    </menu>
```